# multiple selection using the activeadmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I am developing my application in ruby on rails 5 and I am using the activeadmin gem for the CRUD of records, I have a field that the user can select multiple records, I need it to be saved as an array, it is possible that the admin gem allows to use of multiple selection of elements to save them as an array in a field of the database? It would be something like [image: this]. it doesn't need to be a selectbox, I just need to select multiple elements to save them in a field as an array.

UPDATE: I am using mysql, my field is string and I am trying it in the following way in the admin:

```
f.input :jobs_category, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: ["Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Profound"] ,input_html: { value: ["Mild"] }
```

the parameters are these:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"B/9HefHMKZewKlzcuYEuk4FzkQr2JDwmDKZSbiGo0sS9/7VOjXm3Qd3OES3Cmfj9wqF+eq/p+aUkNXF2+6f07A==", "project"=>{"title"=>"asdasdfff", "jobs_category"=>["", "Mild", "Moderate"], "active"=>"0", "content"=>""}, "commit"=>"Guardar Proyecto", "id"=>"fd4f1c1726d25621f1f5e473f6f5ebfca7dde1cf"}
```

but with that type of field it is not being saved in the database, what could I be missing?

Comment: so what is the problem? As I see an array comes from parameters, just store it in the database

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev array is not being saved in the database field, I even have it in the allowed parameters

Comment: how does your column look like?